# Unable to boot Ubuntu from grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub

I installed Ubuntu on a PC that had another Linux distribution already installed. When installing Ubuntu, I chose to delete all data that was written before in the disk, so it probably deleted the other distribution.

The problem is that when I restarted the computer the grub screen appeared, wich states that it was unable to load Ubuntu's kernel:

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device of file completions.

grub>
```

I used `grub>ls` to have an idea of what I could load from here and got this:

```
(lvm/ubuntu--vg-swap_1) (lvm/ubuntu--vg-root) (hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
```

I used `ls` on each of them to check wich one was the actual filesystem and `(hd0,gpt1)` was the only one who didn't throw error: `unknown filesystem`.

I tried doing what this tuto says https://xuri.me/2013/09/03/resolve-ubuntu-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue.html but it still doesn't work.

The file tree of `(hd0,gpt1)` looks like this:

```
hd0,gpt1/
----efi/
--------ubuntu/
------------fw/
------------fwpx64.efi
------------grub.cfg
------------shimx64.efi
------------mx64.efi
------------bootx64.csv
--------boot/
------------bootx64.efi
------------fbx64.efi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to boot with the installation media that you used previously, into rescue mode, and issue the last 2 commands from the tutorial:

$ sudo update-grub

$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda

Comment: Yes, I think there was a problem at the time I first installed Ubuntu. I installed it again with the installation media and it hasn't given me any problems at all. Thank you!